# Powershell Excel Com object SaveAs produces different results on different .XLSX source files

Tags: powershell, com

In my job - I have to process customer supplied XLSX data files from different customers. I need to load the data into SQL using SSIS automation - and the best way I have found is using an SSIS project/package loading the data as pipe-delimited.

In the 2 customer cases I have been working on - the single Excel worksheet containing the data I need (2 different customers... 2 different .XLSX files... both cases - 1 worksheet), both require some pre-manipulation prior to importing.

Customer 1: Column A data contains embedded LineFeed (LF) characters that need to be removed
Customer 2: the 'Active' data includes ~1600 blank lines

I developed the Powershell script for Customer 1 first - and learned the process of using Powershell to open Excel as a COM object... opening the worksheet... selecting all of Column A... cycling through the Column A cells removing the LF chars (and updating the cells)... ending with the following Powershell command:

```
$<ComObjectWorsheetVariable>.SaveAs(($<path\filename.csv'),6)
```

My personal workstation is set to output .CSV as Pipe-delimited and that's exactly what I get.

Using my Customer 1 script as a skeleton, I made the appropriate changes to input and output paths and filenames, and added some script to delete the excess blank lines and included EXACTLY the same Powershell command:

```
$<ComObjectWorsheetVariable>.SaveAs(($<path\filename.csv'),6)
```

THIS output resulted in a quote-qualified, comma separated output that has a trailing comma before the CRLF character in each line. I don't get it... was it the script to delete the blank lines? Using debugging - I stopped the script right after opening the worksheet - then manually executed the Powershell SaveAs using the same syntax as Customer 1, but I still got the quote qualified, comma separated output.

So the actual script that makes the changes didn't factor in... it can't be Excel version because they are both .XLSX files.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

EDIT: found the answer to one part of the question... I was doing a 'SaveAs' from the workbook object and getting the expected pipe-delimited file.

But... with one customer file, I get what is expected - pipe-delimited with the final column terminated with the CRLF. The other customer file is now saving as pipe-delimited, but still has a trailing pipe char in the final column just before the CRLF line terminator. That seems to point to something in the source file (.XLSX)?

Comment: There's not really enough details to say for sure, but you *might* have a single VTAB (ascii char 11) in the last column of data - depending on how you view the csv file it *could* look like a line that ends with an "extra" delimiter because the VTAB might not print on screen. For example, create a worksheet with these values in it: A1=```a```, B1=```b```, C1=```=CHAR(11)``` then manually save it as ```mydata.csv```. If you open it in a hex editor you'll see ```61 2C 62 2C 0B 0D 0A``` but if you do something like ```c:\> type mydata.csv``` you'll see ```a,b,``` with an invisible final vtab.

Comment: Failing that, can you post a small set of sample data that reproduces the issue.

Comment: So, _The other customer file_ has something invisible to the naked eye in a column after the column you expect to be the last one. Because there is a non-empty cell there somewhere, Excel includes it in the UsedRange and saves. Time to clean up that file I would say.

Comment: @Theo - I'm not sure that is the case... when I manually manipulate the file ('Select All) I get that first blank column (N) included. When I delete that column and reselect - I still get Column N in the selection. I've noticed this behavior with deleting rows as well and I haven't researched Excel enough to know how this works or happens. I think I may just take a 'brute force' approach... find the first blank line and column, create a selection of the actual data, copy/paste to a new sheet and save out that new sheet as .CSV.

Thanks everyone for the helpful ideas and quick response.